# Which variable contains the apk path including its basename in gradle/android?

Tags: android, gradle

I have multiple flavours and I need to compute an hash of the apk that is going to be prepare, add the hash to the assets and pack it up again.

Before the flavours the code was as simple as

```
def first = true
def assetsDir = "/path/to/assets"
assembleRelease.doLast {
    def projectLocation = projectDir.toString()
    def apkLocation = projectLocation + "app-release.apk"

    if first {
         exec { executable 'hasher', apkLocation, assetsDir }
         first = false
         assembleRelease.execute()
    }
}
```

I need the variable that contains normally "app-release.apk"

Answer (score 0):

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def apkFile = output.outputFile
}}
```

Comment: Its good to explain parts of your code or write something about it

Comment: @Nezam I think this code is pretty self-explanatory - no redundancy needed here - also just a code hint is often more useful than nothing like you provided

Comment: The code is self-explanatory, but looks really strange that you have to iterate over the variants when you are IN the variant.

Comment: what do you mean with "are IN the variant" ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
def apk = null
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if ( (variant.name).equals("release") ) {
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            apk = output.outputFile
        }
    }
}
println "output file path: " + apk
```

Comment: Looks wrong to iterate over the variants while you are already in the variant.